# Spartacus Customization

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I wanted to make some customization in the OTB functionalities like my profile pages, I wanted to add some new fields, remove existing. What is the best possible approach for that, so that I can extend and customize the Spartacus libraries & HTML files for the functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which component you want to extend you can use a different mechanism. You can find more information about it here https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-and-extending/.

For extending components and the HTML I would advise the two following methods:

1. [CMS component mapping](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/)

For example you can create a new component, extend `UpdateProfileComponent` and provide your own HTML.

You can then inject your custom component like described in the doc.

2. [Outlets](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/outlets)

This mechanism allows you to inject custom HTML in an OOTB component.

Comment: In the first approach(CMS component mapping), all the OOTB form submit actions will call, when i use same form submit in custom html or do we need to do call manually super methods in customcomponent.

Comment: As long as the parent method are public you can call them from your custom html.